# Opening a COM port in QBasic on Windows 7

Tags: serial-port, qbasic

I'm having difficulty opening a COM port in QBasic (obtained from www.qbasic.net) like so

```
OPEN "COM4:9600,N,8,1,BIN" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
```

However when I execute this statement in QBasic the open keyword is highlighted and I get the error message `Bad file name`.

Comment: QB only supports COM1: and COM2:

Comment: Odd, I'm able to open any port on my machine. Even `COM30`!

Comment: What version of QB are you using?

Comment: Try the latest version.

Comment: This link describes why QB only has COM1: and COM2: http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/OPEN_COM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works [FreeBasic](http://www.freebasic.net/)

```
Open Com "COM1:9600,N,8,1" As 1
```

I recommend the FreeBasic IDE [FBIde](http://fbide.freebasic.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Is Com4: one of the available serial ports? Look in control panel and make it is one of the available ports. Also, you must make sure no other programs have the port open.

Comment: COM4 is available and can be written to. Other applications routinely use it, althout none does at the time I run the QBasic program.

Answer (score 0):

"COM4:9600,N,8,1,BIN"

The semantics for opening files changed in Win2K. On NTFS, the colon indicates an Alternate Data Stream, and the DOS use of the colon when opening serial devices was not implemented.

So on Win7, "COM4:9600,N,8,1,BIN" is a bad filename.